# Solace router bridge between two independently managed routers

Tags: solace, solace-mq

I trying to create a **bridge between one Solace router (partner organization) to another Solace router bridge (my organization)**.

Preference is through **Solace router configuration instead of application based bridge**, and it make sense since routers on both ends are from Solace and possibly Solace 3560 Appliance.

I have already developed application based bridge but looking forward to achieve it through router configuration.

Other words, I am looking something which will provide flexible and scalable **interconnect two independently managed Solace routers to exchange agreed messages** on specific queue and topic with guaranteed delivery.

I could not find details to achieve this using router configuration on Solace Developer portal and documents so interested to know implementation ideas to achieve this through router configuration.

Rational:

- No middle-ware application dependency
- Better control over
- Ease of maintenance etc.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are looking for is a VPN bridge.
The VPN bridge will allow you to link the routers together, and exchange guaranteed messages.

More details can be found in the documentation:
http://docs.solace.com/Features/Working-With-Message-VPN-Bridges.htm